Is the $y$-component of projectile motion independent of the $x$-component or not?
In projectile motion, it is said that both the $x$ and $y$ components are independent of each other but according to the equation of the trajectory,
$$y = x \tan\phi - \frac12 g x^2/(u^2\cos^2\phi)$$
$y$ is dependent on $x$. Why?

Welcome to Physics! Please do not post formulae as screenshots, but use MathJax instead. I don't really understand the meaning of some symbols that you used, so I ask you to please edit the question with the correct formatting. This makes it easier for answerers to read your question, comprehend it, and eventually answer it

That is because when you do a dot product with orthogonal dimensions it it will get you. $F_x \cdot \hat{j} = \vec 0$ and similarly $F_y \cdot \hat{i} = \vec 0$. This the mathematical explanation, I also struggle with the intuition and can understand your concern.

One intuitive experience you could try is thinking about throwing a particle at a 2D projectile and blocking its upward trajectory. Will it prevent it from moving horizontally?

The dynamics of each coordinate axis is independent. In other words, you can calculate the motion on the $y$-axis first without knowing the motion on the $x$-axis, and vice-versa. You ddon't need one to compute the other. However, when you have found the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ for the position as a function of time, there will be some relation between $y$ and $x$ due to the fact that the projectile is always at a certain location at a certain height. This relation appears a posteriori in the equations, and it does not affect the dynamics.


In projectile motion, it is said that both the $x$ and $y$ components are independent of each other...

Your assertion begs for context: The $x$ and $y$ components of what?
The answer to my rhetorical question is: It is the $x$ and $y$ components of the Newton's 2nd Law force equation that can be treated independently, as illustrated below.

The equation
$$
\vec F = m\vec a
$$
is a vector equation and once you choose a coordinate system you can dot $\hat x$ or $\hat y$ into both sides of the equation to arrive at:
$$
F_x = m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
F_y = m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\;.\tag{2}
$$

For example, if $F_y = -mg$ and $F_x=0$ we can solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ as:
$$
x(t) = A + Bt\;,\tag{3}
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants
and
$$
y(t) = C + Dt - \frac{1}{2}gt^2\;,\tag{4}
$$
where $C$ and $D$ are constants.
At this point, nothing stops you from solving Eq. (3) for $t=t(x)$ and plugging it into Eq. (4) to arrive at:
$$
y(x)\equiv y(t(x)) = C + D\left(\frac{x-A}{B}\right) - \frac{1}{2}g \left(\frac{(x-A)^2}{B^2}\right)\;.
\tag{5}
$$
Now, be mindful of what Eq. (5) means. It is not a statement about the x-y coordinate system in general. It is a statement that relates the $y$-trajectory of a single point particle to the $x$-trajectory of that same particle at the same point in time. Those two trajectories are not independent, as illustrated in Eqs. (3), (4), and (5).

Nice explanation by far. I think you need to fix the statement "It is statement that relates y-trajectory of the particle with x-trajectory at same moment of time.

Ok, I made that edit.
